# GMap MouseOver seems not to work

Tags: c#, mouseover

Anybody familiar with GMap? Im trying to make use of the Mouse over event but appearantly im doing something wrong. This even there suppose to be a good example here on Stackoverflow which I tried to use.

```
public partial class frmMap : Form
    {

        public void gmap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        double lat = gmap.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;
        double lng = gmap.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;
        lblLatLng.Text = "lat= " + Convert.ToString(lat) + "   lng= " + 
        Convert.ToString(lng);


        // mouseY = e.Location.Y;
        // mouseX = e.Location.X;
        // lblLatLng.Location = new Point(mouseX, mouseY + 10);
    }

public frmMap()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gmap.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
        GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        GMapControl gMap = new GMapControl();
        gmap.MouseDown += gmap_MouseDown;
        gmap.MouseWheel += gmap_MouseWheel;
        gmap.SetPositionByKeywords(Area);
        gmap.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
        gmap.Zoom = 9.5;
    }
```

Above the code im trying to use. My GMap is further working so I have placed the references allready. I just wanted to show in the lblLatLng the current latitude and longitude from the position of the mouse. I beleive this is possible.

Anybody willing to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the code you've posted you've subscribed to the `MouseDown` and `MouseWheel` events, but the handler is for `MouseMove` and isn't linked to the map control..

Comment: The part from mouse down and mousewheel is used for other stuff in my app. But if I understand you right I need to link MouseMove again in de public void MouseMove to the MapControl?

Comment: Yes your comment made me see what I did wrong. I placed in 'frmMap()' the code 'gmap.MouseMove += gmap_MouseMove;' and than it works fine.

Thanks Stuart